# Traits List handler does not react to += list extension

Tags: python, enthought, traits

```
from traits.api import List, HasTraits

class Foo(HasTraits):
   x = List
   def _x_items_changed(self,new):
      print new.added

f = Foo()
f.x = [1,3]
f.x.append(9) #handler reacts!
f.x += [9,10] # handler does not react! Why?
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you're not modifying the list in-place with `+=`, you're assigning it to another, new list...

Comment: `+=` does modify the list in-place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug. `TraitListObject` overrides `extend()` and other mutating methods to propagate changes, but `__iadd__()` was overlooked. The workaround is to use `extend()` instead of `+=`.